# How to underline a Link in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my link:

```
Link("Terms + Conditions", destination: URL(string: "https://my.app/terms_and_conditions.html")!)
```

I'm aware that `Text()` has an `underline()` modifier, however there doesn't seem to be one for `Link()`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 23):

Link has an initialiser that takes a label argument:
`init(destination: URL, label: () -> Label)`

So for your example, you would need to set up a `Text("Terms + Conditions")` view as the label, and use the `.underline()` modifier on the text view to get the intended outcome.

Using Apples website as an example:

```
Link(destination: URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!, label: {
    Text("Apple")
        .underline()
})
```